# How to find the alias for a keystore entry using KeyStore Explorer program?

Tags: alias, keystore

I have the file open in the program, but I don't understand where the *Alias* is or what it is called in the program.

Answer (score 2):

The alias is just the name of the keystore entry:

[image]

Comment: Exactly. The official Keystore Explorer [documentation](https://keystore-explorer.org/doc/5.4/overview.html#keystore-entries) also mentions that: "Entry Name - entry's alias name."